# How to pass values to js in cocos2d-iphone jsbindings?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm cooking a cocos2d-iphone(v2.1) project with jsbindings. The cocos2d view running main.js in my UIKit view works properly. Now I want to add a new feature to show different animation by user input.

I want to know how to pass values to the js file in objective-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

In `jsb_core.h`, there is a method called: `-(BOOL) evalString:(NSString*)string outVal:(jsval*)outVal;`. With this method, I can call functions in my `main.js` from my objective-c code.

So I defined a function in my `main.js` file:

```
function test(values) {
  cc.log(values);
}
```

Then I can call it from my objective-c code like this:

```
CCDirectorIOS *director = (CCDirectorIOS *)[CCDirector sharedDirector];
if(director.runningScene) {
  [[JSBCore sharedInstance] evalString:@"test('ValueToPass');" outVal:nil];
}
```